# How to put TempData Array in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to post links to View but I need help, first I created an string array for this.

```
    string[] publicPath = new string[] { "/images/" + fileName };
    TempData["link"] = publicPath;
    ViewBag.link = TempData["link"];
```

After that this is my .cshtml;

```
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.link)
    {
         <textarea cols="102" rows="5" disabled="disabled" style="resize:none;">HELP!</textarea><br />
    }
```

I have no problem putting the variable into TempData, but I could not understand how to use it in View.
 Thank you in advance, best regards ...

Comment: What is your requirement?When using your code,it could display the textarea successfully.What do you want to use the ViewBag in the View?

Comment: I want to show some of local path to text area. I need array so i created a list<string> for this and added but i don't know how to show it in text area. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

There's no info here about your actual issue, but I'd imagine it's down to working with dynamics. `ViewBag` is what's referred to as a dynamic. This allows you to just arbitrarily set a property like `ViewBag.link`, without having to explicitly define a property, but it also means that `ViewBag.link` doesn't have a known type. As such, you can't just use it in something like a `foreach` because you must provide an enumerable in that context, and the compiler has no idea if `ViewBag.link` is an enumerable type or not.

You're going to have to cast it, first, to use it.

```
@foreach (var item in (string[])ViewBag.link)
```

Be careful with this, though. Here, you know it's a `string[]`, but if you change the type of what you're stuffing into `ViewBag.link`, this code here won't complain. It will blow up during runtime, of course, with an `InvalidCastException`, but you won't know that until it blows up. In general, you should avoid using dynamics, like `ViewBag`, for this reason. Instead, use a view model class and strongly type your view with that as its model. Then, you don't have to worry about casting, and you'll get all the standard intellisense and compile-time checking you'd expect.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to post multiple images to a localpath and set their publicPath to TempData for show the URL via textarea tag. Thanks for answer sir...

Comment: I created a model as you said `public class Adres { public string Adress { get; set; } }` then use @model on top of .cshtml page `@model IEnumarable<Example.Model.Adres>` this is my final foreach `@foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<Adres>)TempData["link"])
            {
                <textarea cols="102" rows="5" disabled="disabled" style="resize:none;">@item.Adress</textarea><br />
            }` and it crashed .net core is very difficult then i think.

Comment: No. You can't just cast something like `TempData["foo"]` to a type. `TempData` is a `Dictionary<string, string>`, so you're attempt to arbitrary cast a string to `IEnumerable<Adres>`. Of course that failed. New up the view model in your action, set the appropriate properties and such via `TempData` or whatever in the action. Then, return that model to the view and use *it* in your view.